# Imacros firefox loop every 50 urls and wait for fews seconds and continue

Tags: loops, csv, firefox, wait, imacros

```
TAB T=1
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !DATASOURCE D:\linkedprofileurls.csv
SET !LOOP 2                 
'SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}}
URL GOTO={{!COL1}}
```

Above is current macro which I am using but do have code to stop/pause at every 50th, 100th etc url.

When I entered 10000 number in Max: in repeat macro and clicked play (loop) it continues till the end of 10000th url without stop/pause on every 50th, 100th url.

Imacro have to wait for 10 seconds after opening 50th url and continue from 51st url and wait for 10 seconds at 100th url and so on from excel csv file.

Comment: Please be specific when asking your question. What exactly is the problem you are facing? What is your desired outcome?

Comment: it is unclear what u asking. make it short